# expo start --tunnel doesn't work. Error starting ngrok: Starting tunnels timed out

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, ngrok, tunnel

I am building a project in react native and using expo-cli@6.3.2 for almost 5 months, never had issue doing expo start --tunnel, however today I tried to do it and it displays this odd error.

expo start --tunnel

```
`PS F:\cenas\Cenas> expo start --tunnel   

This command is being executed with the global Expo CLI. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421
To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:
› npx expo start

Starting project at F:\cenas\Cenas
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - react-native - expected version: 0.70.8 - actual version installed: 0.70.5
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo doctor --fix-dependencies,
or install individual packages by running expo install [package-name ...]
Starting Metro Bundler
Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on the connected Android device.
Using legacy dev server: false
Error starting ngrok: Starting tunnels timed out
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Started Metro Bundler
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▄▄ ▀ ██ █ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ ██▄▀ █   ▄█ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ ██▀▄ ▄ ██▀█ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ ▀▄█ ▀ ▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█▄ ▀  ▀▄██▄▀█▄██▀ █▄█▀█▀▀▄█
█▄█ ▄ ▄▄▄█▄██▄█ ▄ ▀███▄▀▀ █
█▀ █ ██▄▀ ▄ █▀█▄ █ ▄▀▀█▀ ██
█ ▄▄ ▄ ▄▀▄█▄█▀▄█ ▄▀ ██▄▀  █
█▄██▄██▄█ ▀▄ ▄▄ █ ▄▄▄  ▄▀▄█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██ ▄▀▄  █ █▄█ ███ █
█ █   █ █ ▄ ▄ ██▄ ▄  ▄ █▀▀█
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀▄▀  █▄ ▄█▀▀▄█   █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄██▄▄▄▄█▄▄███▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://192......
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.`
```

Comment: Could you run the server with the global version of react native with `npx  expo start --tunnel` ?

Comment: No, I cannot run the server using npx, it has the same behavior.